# CSV file downloading from colums and then save

Tags: php, csv, download, save

I'm facing a problem with csv file. I want to ask if there is way how to download from csv lines (url) in column A and then save them in a directory which is in column B and if needed overwrite the images.
for example:

```
http://data.militarysklad.cz/attach/eobchod/foto/125432dtc.jpg**;**/images/catalog/jjjj.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

```
1.

allow_url_fopen set to true

<?php
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $url = $data[0];
        $path = $data[1];
        file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url));
    }
   fclose($handle);
}
?>

2. cURL

<?php
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $url = $data[0];
        $path = $data[1];

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $fp = fopen($path, 'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```